# create a new columns in when() functions in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this df with id and changes_count columns. the value '1' is the mean increase and the value '2' is the mean decrease and the value '0' mean that don't make any changes.

| id | changes_count |
| --- | --- |
| 9625 | 1 |
| 9625 | 2 |
| 9625 | 1 |
| 9625 | 1 |
| 9625 | 0 |
| 8643 | 1 |
| 8643 | 2 |
| 8643 | 2 |
| 8643 | 0 |
| 8643 | 0 |

finally, I want that my df look like this:

| id | increase | decrease |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9625 | 3 | 1 |
| 8643 | 1 | 2 |

I thought to use the .withColumn function but I feel that something wrong.

`df.withColumn('dec', F.when(F.col("changes_count") == 1, 1).otherwise(0))`

and after that use the .groupBy function but I can't make a count for my changes_count column.

thanks for all!

Comment: count the number of 1s for `increase` and number of 2s for `decrease` grouped at `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(count(when(col("changes_count") == 1, 1)).alias("increase"), \
                    count(when(col("changes_count") == 2, 1)).alias("decrease")).display()
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+--------+
|  id|increase|decrease|
+----+--------+--------+
|9625|       3|       1|
|8643|       1|       2|
+----+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work (using - when and grouping)

```
df.withColumn("increase", F.when(F.col("changes_count") == 1, 1))\
.withColumn("decrease", F.when(F.col("changes_count") == 2, 1))\
.groupBy("id")\
.agg(F.sum("increase").alias("increase"), F.sum("decrease").alias("decrease"))\
.show()
```

If using Spark 3.0.0 + you can utilize [count_if](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#count_if) :

```
df.groupBy("id")\
.agg(F.expr("count_if(changes_count  = 1)").alias("increase"),F.expr("count_if(changes_count  = 2)").alias("decrease"))\
.show()
```

Input:

```
+----+-------------+
|  id|changes_count|
+----+-------------+
|9625|            1|
|9625|            2|
|9625|            1|
|9625|            1|
|9625|            0|
|8643|            1|
|8643|            2|
|8643|            2|
|8643|            0|
|8643|            0|
+----+-------------+
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+--------+
|  id|increase|decrease|
+----+--------+--------+
|9625|       3|       1|
|8643|       1|       2|
+----+--------+--------+
```